# how to compile .js files with Plugin.registerCompiler?

Tags: meteor

It seems only files with formats not ending .js can be compiled. How would I go about targeting regular .js files? I'm looking to make some changes to my code as part of the build process.

Comment: AFAIK this isn't possible at the moment, because there are already compilers registered for that extension. You'd have to rename your files to something else -- which, if we are really going to attach additional semantics to them, might even be the most appropriate choice.

Comment: Meteor 1.2 is supporting ES6 transpilation on .js files, so the updated build system will allow this in the upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out the new Build Plugins API (which isn't documented yet on docs.meteor.com) supports it today: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Build-Plugins-API ...thanks for your answers guys.